# SlidingUpPanelLayout with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).
If I use a `SlidingUpPanelLayout  layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);`into the onCreateView it crashes with a

```
Fatal exception: main
android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

How can I use this library with fragments?
Thanks.

EDIT: my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondor"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom">

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#99000000">

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp">
</View>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblExpenseCancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:shadowColor="#5a5a5a"
    android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="0.0"
    android:shadowRadius="20"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rotaimg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/unnamed"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

 <View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp">
</View>


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#aa0a2e"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rappdistr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#99000000">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:text="Social"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

There is a SlidingUpPanelLayout and the two child LinearLayout with some objects like textviews and images.

Comment: Can you post your code? So we can suggest how to fix :)